# how to read from Xml File and put the list of element in listView on the form

Tags: c#

i have my xml file "modules.xml", from which i m trying to load the Name of every module in the listView in my form. i have tried the following code, its not giving me error neither working at all.

modules.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Modules>
  <Module>
    <Code>3SFE504</Code>
    <Name>Algorithms and Data Structures</Name>
    <Capacity>5</Capacity>
    <Semester>1</Semester>
    <Prerequisites>none</Prerequisites>
    <LectureSlot>Monday 9-11</LectureSlot>
    <TutorialSlot>Monday 11-1pm</TutorialSlot>
  </Module> -
  <Module>
    <Code>3SFE508</Code>
    <Name>3D Graphics 1</Name>
    <Capacity>5</Capacity>
    <Semester>1</Semester>
    <Prerequisites>none</Prerequisites>
    <LectureSlot>Monday 2-4pm</LectureSlot>
    <TutorialSlot>Monday 4-6pm</TutorialSlot>
  </Module> -
  <Module>
    <Code>3SFE513</Code>
    <Name>Event-Driven Programming</Name>
    <Capacity>10</Capacity>
    <Semester>1</Semester>
    <Prerequisites>none</Prerequisites>
    <LectureSlot>Tuesday 9-11</LectureSlot>
    <TutorialSlot>Tuesday 11-1pm</TutorialSlot>
  </Module>
  <Module>
    <Code>3SFE514</Code>
    <Name>Object-Oriented Design</Name>
    <Capacity>10</Capacity>
    <Semester>1</Semester>
    <Prerequisites>none</Prerequisites>
    <LectureSlot>Tuesday 2-4pm</LectureSlot>
    <TutorialSlot>Tuesday 4-6pm</TutorialSlot>
  </Module> -
  <Module>
    <Code>3SFE516</Code>
    <Name>Requirements Engineering</Name>
    <Capacity>10</Capacity>
    <Semester>1</Semester>
    <Prerequisites>none</Prerequisites>
    <LectureSlot>Thursday 9-11</LectureSlot>
    <TutorialSlot>Thursday 11-1pm</TutorialSlot>
  </Module>
  <Module>
    <Code>3SFE599</Code>
    <Name>Introduction to AI</Name>
    <Capacity>5</Capacity>
    <Semester>1</Semester>
    <Prerequisites>none</Prerequisites>
    <LectureSlot>Thursday 2-4pm</LectureSlot>
    <TutorialSlot>Monday 9-11</TutorialSlot>
  </Module> -
  <Module>
    <Code>3SFE540</Code>
    <Name>Java Mobile Application Development</Name>
    <Capacity>5</Capacity>
    <Semester>1</Semester>
    <Prerequisites>3SFE514</Prerequisites>
    <LectureSlot>Monday 11-1pm</LectureSlot>
    <TutorialSlot>Monday 2-4pm</TutorialSlot>
  </Module>
  <Module>
    <Code>3SFE541</Code>
    <Name>C# .Net Framework Programming</Name>
    <Capacity>5</Capacity>
    <Semester>1</Semester>
    <Prerequisites>3SFE514</Prerequisites>
    <LectureSlot>Monday 4-6pm</LectureSlot>
    <TutorialSlot>Tuesday 9-11</TutorialSlot>
  </Module>
  <Module>
    <Code>3SFE515</Code>
    <Name>Software Engineering Group Project</Name>
    <Capacity>5</Capacity>
    <Semester>2</Semester>
    <Prerequisites>3SFE514</Prerequisites>
    <LectureSlot>Monday 9-11</LectureSlot>
    <TutorialSlot>Monday 11-1pm</TutorialSlot>
  </Module>
  <Module>
    <Code>3SFE519</Code>
    <Name>Software Engineering</Name>
    <Capacity>10</Capacity>
    <Semester>2</Semester>
    <Prerequisites>none</Prerequisites>
    <LectureSlot>Monday 2-4pm</LectureSlot>
    <TutorialSlot>Monday 4-6pm</TutorialSlot>
  </Module>
  <Module>
    <Code>3SFE542</Code>
    <Name>Mobile User Interface Development</Name>
    <Capacity>5</Capacity>
    <Semester>2</Semester>
    <Prerequisites>3SFE540</Prerequisites>
    <LectureSlot>Tuesday 9-11</LectureSlot>
    <TutorialSlot>Tuesday 11-1pm</TutorialSlot>
  </Module>
  <Module>
    <Code>3MTS594</Code>
    <Name>Interactive Multimedia</Name>
    <Capacity>5</Capacity>
    <Semester>2</Semester>
    <Prerequisites>none</Prerequisites>
    <LectureSlot>Tuesday 2-4pm</LectureSlot>
    <TutorialSlot>Tuesday 4-6pm</TutorialSlot>
  </Module>
  <Module>
    <Code>3SFE555</Code>
    <Name>Concurrent Programming</Name>
    <Capacity>5</Capacity>
    <Semester>2</Semester>
    <Prerequisites>none</Prerequisites>
    <LectureSlot>Thursday 9-11</LectureSlot>
    <TutorialSlot>Thursday 11-1pm</TutorialSlot>
  </Module>
  <Module>
    <Code>3SFE557</Code>
    <Name>Mobile Gaming</Name>
    <Capacity>10</Capacity>
    <Semester>2</Semester>
    <Prerequisites>none</Prerequisites>
    <LectureSlot>Thursday 9-11</LectureSlot>
    <TutorialSlot>Monday 9-11</TutorialSlot>
  </Module>
  <Module>
    <Code>3SFE500</Code>
    <Name>Intelligent Systems</Name>
    <Capacity>10</Capacity>
    <Semester>2</Semester>
    <Prerequisites>3SFE599</Prerequisites>
    <LectureSlot>Monday 11-1pm</LectureSlot>
    <TutorialSlot>Monday 2-4pm</TutorialSlot>
  </Module>
  <Module>
    <Code>3SFE501</Code>
    <Name>3D Graphics II</Name>
    <Capacity>10</Capacity>
    <Semester>2</Semester>
    <Prerequisites>3SFE508</Prerequisites>
    <LectureSlot>Monday 4-6pm</LectureSlot>
    <TutorialSlot>Tuesday 9-11</TutorialSlot>
  </Module>
</Modules>
```

.cs file is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

namespace cw
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {    
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String workingDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader(workingDir + @"\modules.xml");
            XmlNodeType type;

            Console.WriteLine("BaseURI:" + textReader.BaseURI);


            while (textReader.Read())
            {
                type = textReader.NodeType;


                if (type == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    if (textReader.Name == "Name")
                    {
                        textReader.Read();
                        listView1.Items.Add(textReader.Value);
                    }


                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
            textReader.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

i carried out a text and concluded that my while loop is working but the if statment isn't working.

Comment: @L.B's answer suggest's a clean way of doing it. However, what is wrong with your code. What do you mean when you say it is not working. It works fine for me!

Comment: i have deleted the while and the if Statement from my code and replaced the whole method by the code that LB provided me. the error is coming on "xmlstr" it says that "the name doesn't exists in the current context"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951026/c-sharp-how-to-get-xml-elements-and-output-to-labels

Comment: Your teacher should tell you to stop using `new XmlTextReader()`. It's been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` instead. Same for `XmlTextWriter`. He should also tell you to put your `XmlReader` into a `using` block.

Answer (score 1):

using Linq2Xml

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xmlstr));
List<string> modules = xDoc
    .Descendants("Module")
    .Select(n => n.Element("Name").Value)
    .ToList();

foreach(var item in modules)
    listView1.Items.Add(item);
```

Comment: @ZainAfzal, add a `var` in front of item. Don't just copy&paste, try to understand the code.

Comment: i did but now its not accpeting "xmlstr".dont i have to specify the location or the name of my xml file instead of "xmlstr"

Comment: @ZainAfzal I tested your case by loading xml from a string. you can use `XDocument.Load(File.Open(.....))` if you want to load from file. I don't see any effort from you. Just look at the help of `XDocument`

Comment: @ZainAfzal, of course you need to specify the location! xmlstr is just a variable that you need to set according to your needs.

Comment: @L.B, can I ask, why you would need to use File.Open(..) or StreamReader(), when it works like a charm using just a simple path instead?

Comment: @walther **StringReader** (not StreamReader) is needed when you load xml from  string variable, but File.Open?, just habbit.

Comment: @L.B, yes, wanted to write StringReader, wrote StreamReader instead :) My bad. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: thanks for you efforts but finally got it to work just needed to change the "m" of the module to "M" and move the whole method to to "public form1"...

Answer (score 0):

> As per your xml Structure. you can use directly let DataSet to read
>   your xml file using [DataSet.ReadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/55hehd8c.aspx)(filepath) method. you can
>   specify your xml Schema also.

It is working at my side. Try this:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  ds.ReadXml("c:\\xmlFile.xml");

        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            foreach (DataRow item in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(item["Name"].ToString());
            }
        }
```

If you consider more complex XML then i suggest  you to go through [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) as @L.B suggested.

Comment: `DataSet` is a poor general solution, as it will only work for XML that could be mapped to a relational structure.

Comment: yes. i agree with you but the xml structure is too much simple that can be imported using dataset. if it have little hard to filter tags from xml and relational structure then i will consider Linq2Xml..

Comment: Oh, I know it will work in this case. I meant only that `DataSet` doesn't always work. For example, if the same element has "two parent" elements, then it will either fail, or else will produce two tables when one was expected.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("XMLFile1.xml"));
        lsview.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        lsview.DataBind();
```

code in aspx

```
<asp:ListView ID="lsview" runat="server" >
<ItemTemplate>
<%# Eval("Name") %>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```